# Switching to a fragment on click from the adapter

Tags: java, android, adapter, android-context

I have a BackStack in the project, to make the transition from fragment to fragment I use the following

```
 public void showFragment(@NonNull Fragment fragment) {
        showFragment(fragment, true);
    }

    public void showFragment(@NonNull Fragment fragment, boolean addToBackStack) {
        if (curFragment != null && addToBackStack) {
            pushFragmentToBackStack(curTabId, curFragment);
        }
        replaceFragment(fragment);
    }
```

```
 private void replaceFragment(@NonNull Fragment fragment) {
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction tr = fm.beginTransaction();
        tr.replace(R.id.content, fragment);
        tr.commitAllowingStateLoss();
        curFragment = fragment;
    }
```

But I need to step into fragment by clicking item from recyclerView, to do this, I added a position for each `item`.
And `onBindViewHolder` in `Adapter` added this

```
 @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MenuViewHolder holder, int position) {
        ItemMenu Item = ItemMenuList.get(position);

        holder.tv_menu.setText(Item.getMenuText());

        holder.getAdapterPosition();

        holder.cv_menu.setOnClickListener(v ->
        {
            switch (Item.getInitialPositon()) {
                case 0: {
                    ((MainActivity) requireActivity()).showFragment(Fragment_Tasks.newInstance());
                    break;
                }
                case 1: {

                    break;
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

The problem is that the transition requires `context()`. How to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either pass a `Context` reference into your adapter or a callback which you can use to pass the job of click handling to the activity/fragment.

For an example with a callback, we can define an interface:

```
interface OnItemClickListener {
     void onItemClick(...);
}
```

Pass this into the adapter via the constructor, then trigger it when your item is clicked. So in `onBindViewHolder`:

```
holder.cvMenu.setOnClickListener(v -> {
    itemClickListener.onItemClick(...);
});
```

Comment: Can you describe a way with `callback` or throw some example?

Comment: Added some clarity

Answer (score 0):

You can get context from your ViewHolder

```
holder.itemView.getContext()
```

But it's not really recommended

The best practice is you add interface for onclick in adapter then implement it to your fragment